# Redux with reusable react components

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to create custom `Select` component, that will act pretty much like a normal HTML `select`, but I am having issues hooking the `Select` component up to redux to manage when the option list is shown or hidden.  I have got it working so far that when putting multiple `Select` components on the screen, that they are all showing / hiding their option list when I click on any of them.  I am toggling the actual showing/hiding by checking the props in my `styled-component` My (simplified)code so far -

Select.jsx

```
const DropDown = styled.div`
    ...
    display: ${props => props.dropDownShown ? 'block' : 'none'};
    ...
`;

const Select = ({toggleDropDown, dropDownShown}) => (
    <div>
        <span class="input" onClick={() => toggleDropDown()}>
            <span>Item 1</span>
            <img src={selectArrowClear}/>
        </span>
        <DropDown dropDownShown={dropDownShown}>
            <Option>Item 1</Option>
            <Option>Item 2</Option>
            <Option>Item 3</Option>
        </DropDown>
    </div>
);

export default Select;
```

SelectContainer.jsx

```
const toggleDropDown = () => ({
    type: 'TOGGLE_DROP_DOWN'
});


const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    dropDownShown: state.select.dropDownShown
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    toggleDropDown: () => {
        dispatch(toggleDropDown());
    }
});

const SelectContainer = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(Select);

export default SelectContainer;
```

SelectReducer.js

```
const initialState = { dropDownShown: false };

const select = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'TOGGLE_DROP_DOWN': {
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                dropDownShown: !state.dropDownShown
            });
        }
        default: return state;
    }
};

export default select;
```

What do I need to do in order to be able to have multiple `<SelectContainer />` components to be rendered on the same screen that interact independantly of each other?

Comment: Instead of using redux store, you can utilize the state. So that each <Select /> Component state will have it's own memory. Your code will be lot more simpler. I think it's overkill to use redux here...

Comment: Is it good practice to have some components manage their own state, and other parts of the application use redux?  I did feel like using redux for something so trivial felt wrong

Comment: As of my knowledge we can use both state and redux store at same time. What you gonna do with data of Opened or Closed selected components is what matters here. If you need this data to be synced with your database, then its fine you use redux store, or you if you just wanted a Select component which work on its own, then state is perfectly fine.

Comment: ok, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Looks like my architecture was a overcomplicated - after reading https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/1287 and @Sivadass N comment, i'll manage the `Select`s state with `setState` and leave redux for the more global actions.